# How do you restart a query using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm finishing up the Core Data tutorial, and it suggests trying to convert to using a NSFetchedResultsController.  So I've got it so that I can query the existing data, but when I add a row at the beginning, tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath calls NSFetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath, but that still returns the old zeroth object instead of the new one.  Is there something I need to do to flush that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set your view controller as the fetched results controller's delegate and implemented the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)?  If so, you should not have to perform the fetch again, the fetched results controller will invoke the delegate methods in response to changes.

(Note, though, the caution in [NSFetchedResultsController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFetchedResultsController) regarding the implementation of the table view data source methods.)

Comment: This has got to be the right answer, at least better than redoing the fetch every time, but I'm getting an uncaught exception in [managedObjectContext save:&error] right after the didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath finishes.

Comment: What is the exception, and in what method?

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has answered yet, so I'll add my guess. It looks like [this link](http://macgeeks.cn/bbs/viewtopic.php?id=6446) might be relevant. The suggestion there is that calling either of these two methods should get an update for you:

```
-[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges]
-[NSManagedObjectContext save]
```

Perhaps the [documentation for `NSManagedObjectContext`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will be useful.

Comment: Actually, I was already doing the [managedContext save]; but there was a clue in there.

Answer (score 2):

There was a clue in the link that Naaf provided.  Turns out that after doing the save, I needed to call -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch] again.